# Auto Increment Reference of Sheet EXCEL

Tags: excel

Hi people I have a problem with a function in excel.
I have many reference to many sheets, that way.

```
='01'!$S$9
='02'!$S$9
```

And I want that excel automatically increment the number of reference of page that way.

```
='01'!$S$9
='02'!$S$9
.
.
.
='09'!$S$9
```

but excel 
just copy the values, any idea? 
I try to google it but I cant find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'0",ROW(),"'!$S$9"))
```

EDIT: In this case, `ROW()` will return 1 for first row. You might have to modify this formula appropriately for your scenario.